# What does " equally desperate measures" mean here?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

In the first chapter of  the book "We were liars", there is a sentence said " So much in love that equally desperate measures must be taken " i am struggling with understanding this " equally desperate measures"

Comment: What was the full sentence? Or is that it?

Comment: It’s not quoted properly, so really can’t be answered in its current form.

Comment: Does the previous sentence refer to taking some kind of measure (doing something to try to solve a problem)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an example of ellipsis: a part of the sentence is left out because it's taken to be understood. Basically, the sentence quoted in full should read

> So much in *love* that equally desperate measures (*as love*) must be taken.

Leaving out the bracketed element (ellipsis) saves time, space, and makes the sentence more readable.

Comment: What is a desperate measures , i searched it on google and it said " desperate mean you are in a hopeless situation " ? So how it can be "desperate measures" ?

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives this definition of *desperate*: **involving or employing extreme measures in an attempt to escape defeat or frustration**. I hope that clears things up. I thought the issue was syntactic rather than semantic.